# Get all uploaded images using REST api

Tags: media, rest-api

I need to get all the images that are uploaded in my wordpress installation using the REST API.
I've tried using the `wp-json/wp/v2/media` endpoint but it will give me only the last 10 images uploaded that are attached to the last published post but this isn't what I was expectinng.

How I can get all the images that are uploaded in wordpress unsing the rest api?

Comment: Do you just need to request more pages from the API? Look in the response headers: there should be two headers there with the max number of pages and total number of images. See https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/

Comment: I need to get all the media uploaded. I want to get at least 20 images because I will not query the api more than once, I'm working on a slideshow so I will not have pagination but only x images to display

Comment: Try adding `?per_page=20` then, or another limit up to 100. But there's no reason you can't use the API more than once to build up a list in pages, either at the beginning or dynamically as they're needed.

Comment: @Rup solved,thanks for the help. I just need a single ajax call to fetch the images I need for the slider. it will be unuseful for my scope to make multiple ajax calls, it doesn't have any sense in a slider.

Answer (score 0):

add per_page: 100 as params
also set page: 1 for first 100 and 2 for next 100

Have a look:- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mbd5F.png

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).